# Map output statuses were N bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize - Error in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, akka

I am facing this error in a simple spark job. I don't want to increase the spark.akka.frameSize before investigating the cause.

Error in spark reduceByKey Operation-

```
16/07/04 19:50:43 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Map output statuses were 209098002 bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize (104857600 bytes).
16/07/04 19:50:46 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Map output statuses were 209098002 bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize (104857600 bytes).
16/07/04 19:50:49 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Map output statuses were 209098002 bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize (104857600 bytes).
16/07/04 19:50:49 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Map output statuses were 209098002 bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize (104857600 bytes).
```

Code -

```
val events = inputFilesRdd.map {
      // Emit : (id, user, product) -> date
      splits => (splits(11), splits(4), splits(2)) -> splits(1)
    }.reduceByKey((left, right) => minString(left, right))
```

minString is a simple function for comparing string. Th expected data size is higher Gigs.

The input files are gzipped.

Any tips on this error ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem?

Comment: Wasn't able to investigate the cause. Increasing the akka frame size fixes it.